NavHost while navigate to destination triggers recomposition for a few times
There is min reproducible example of code:
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowScope
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyVerticalGrid
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.itemsIndexed
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.itemsIndexed
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.RectangleShape
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.krokosha.focusrequester2.ui.theme.Test_delete_itTheme

private const val FIRST_SCREEN_ROUTE = "first_screen"
private const val SECOND_SCREEN_ROUTE = "second_screen"

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Test_delete_itTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    shape = RectangleShape
                ) {
                    Greeting()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    val navigator: NavHostController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navigator,
        startDestination = FIRST_SCREEN_ROUTE
    ) {
        composable(FIRST_SCREEN_ROUTE) {
            Log.e("HERE", "1 SCREEN")
            FirstScreen(onClick = { navigator.navigate(SECOND_SCREEN_ROUTE) }) }
        composable(SECOND_SCREEN_ROUTE) {
            Log.e("HERE", "2 SCREEN")
            SecondScreen() }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.1f)),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "SECOND SCREEN")
    }
}

@Composable
fun FirstScreen(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        LeftPanel()
        RightPanel(onClick = onClick)
    }
}

@Composable
fun RowScope.LeftPanel() {
    val buttons: List<String> by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(List(5) { "Button ${it + 1}" }) }

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Blue.copy(alpha = 0.1f))
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .weight(1f),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(
            items = buttons,
            key = { idx, _ -> idx }
        ) { idx, _ ->
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier,
                onClick = { /* nothing */ }
            ) {
                Text(text = "Left Panel: $idx")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RowScope.RightPanel(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    val buttons: List<String> by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(List(4) { "Button ${it + 1}" }) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.1f))
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .weight(1f),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            itemsIndexed(
                items = buttons,
                key = { idx, _ -> idx }
            ) { idx, _ ->
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        onClick()
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Right Panel: $idx")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I left a log in composable(FIRST_SCREEN_ROUTE) and in composable(SECOND_SCREEN_ROUTE). When I press the button on the right panel (on the screen), I see the following in the log (and the same in LayoutInspector):
13:26:43.572  E  1 SCREEN
13:26:46.570  E  1 SCREEN
13:26:46.580  E  2 SCREEN
13:26:46.661  E  1 SCREEN
13:26:46.668  E  2 SCREEN
13:26:47.369  E  2 SCREEN
13:26:47.438  E  2 SCREEN

Question: How is it possible that even in the simplest example with the most basic navigation, recomposition occurs multiple times when switching screens?
UPD
Finally, the problem has been fixed this way:
The way logs are placed is slightly incorrect. Recomposition, when the UI changes, always starts at the highest parent element. Then it begins to descend through the child elements and checks their parameters. If any of them have changed, the child elements are recomposed. In this case (navigating to a new screen), Greeting method is being recomposed, meaning it is entirely re-executed, which is why the logs are triggered. So, first, it is necessary to move the logs inside the FirstScreen and SecondScreen functions. Now we can see that these functions are indeed being redrawn suspiciously many times.
The problem lies in this line:
FirstScreen(onClick = { navigator.navigate(SECOND_SCREEN_ROUTE) }) }
The issue is that the click handler code is not stable.
To fix this, it is necessary to write it like this:
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    val navigator: NavHostController = rememberNavController()

    val click = remember { { navigator.navigate(SECOND_SCREEN_ROUTE) } }

    NavHost(
        navController = navigator,
        startDestination = FIRST_SCREEN_ROUTE
    ) {


        composable(FIRST_SCREEN_ROUTE) {
            FirstScreen(onClick = { click() })
        }
        composable(SECOND_SCREEN_ROUTE) {
            SecondScreen()
        }
    }
}


Welcome to Compose!
So in compose scope when something change it's trigger so fast, that might even not captured on Logs. this is what we call recomposition
So How do you use a "Normal Function" in compose?
if you want it triggered Once when compose is created, you can use the side effect for more information you can see the documentation

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    Log.d("something", "something")
}

//or triggered on mutablestate change
var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

LaunchedEffect(count) {
    Log.d("something", "something ${count}")
}

Button(onClick= {
   //the onclick on Button is triggered every time you clicked so no worry.
   count += 1
}) {
   Text("Count")
}


Hope this Helpful.
